# GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found) error after login

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

After logged in, I am getting this error:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found) error after login
```

It may be because of this, log out is not happening properly.

This is my github repository: https://github.com/shreedharshetty/richapp

You can login using the username: [redacted] and password: [redacted].

Please help me to come out of this error.

Edit *** This is an error in the Gem and there is a fix coming:

https://github.com/tscolari/jquery-mobile-rails/pull/8

Comment: Looks like the path to the ajax-loader.gif may be wrong, or maybe the gif doesn't exist.

Comment: http://sharp-galaxy-5680.heroku.com this the project deployed in heroku

Comment: Logging into where?  Log out of where?  What's that a git repo for?  What's the problem?

Comment: i didn't give any path for myself, may be its auto generated from jquery.

Comment: 404 error means the file's not found.  Are you sure the image is in the right folder, and that the path is right?

Comment: @Rocket i have given the heroku link, please refer the link and log in to app, then you can check error in console.

Comment: @shreedhar: The error is there without needing to login.

Comment: @Rocket yes i can see that file doesn't exists in that path. but i don't why that is happening since that path is generated from jquery.

Comment: @Rocket oh k, but sometimes, after logged in, error occurs and sometimes without login error occurs. Any solutions please?

Comment: @shreedhar: The path to the image is actually in your CSS file.

Comment: @Rocket instead of giving heroku link, i gave that.

Comment: tha path for the image is  /assets/images/ajax-loader.gif  normally in  rails 3 it must be /assets/ajax-loader.gif without /images, in your assets images there is no such image, at least looking at your github repo

Comment: @shreedhar: How were we supposed to login without a real link to the app?  I removed the username/password from the question because I didn't know what they were for.

Comment: Posting code/a link and saying "fix this" isn't how things work around here.  You need to give us detail about your problem, and show that you tried to fix it yourself before asking for help.

Comment: @Rocket clearly i have given the heroku link for the app, sharp-galaxy-5680.heroku.com . as you said if there is no need of logging in.

Comment: and why the error says that ajax-loader.gif is missing if in public/assets/ you have images only in PNG format? ajax-loader.png

Comment: @Rocket i have no such files in assets. i tried my self to solve the problem, ajax-loader.gif is the thing which is auto generated from jquery-rails, as i dint give anywhere in my app. and i have given the github repo for the reference, and heroku link is to check the error. and thanks for your help.

Comment: you have no such files? https://github.com/shreedharshetty/richapp/tree/master/public/assets/jquery-mobile

you are saying that the exemple on heroku and the github repo is not  the same project/app?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 i mean to say, manually i didn't give any path. its jquery thing. yes both are same application. and thanks, i ll try your answer for sure. thanks a lot.

Comment: yes man, I know that this path is generated by JS.. but look with google-inspect, I can see that you have this image icons-18-white.png in your app and it is found by the app cause it has the right path: http://sharp-galaxy-5680.heroku.com/assets/jquery-mobile/icons-18-white-7148db9937919eefc9b37c0f61c08bd4.png  and also this image you have in the public / assets / jquery-mobile path. Startin from here I can suppose that you don't have such image ajax-loader.gif on your server, this is a JS mistake or the file is not there..

Comment: if the JS found this icons-18-white.png file then it should find the ajax-loader.png too, but for the loader you have the wrong path /assets/images etc.. when it should be  assets/jquery-mobile/ajax-loader.png. And since you don't know how to deal with JS code, just create this path on the server in public/assets/images and drop there a file called ajax-loader.gif and see if it's working, take the image from here http://www.patsyboutique.be/images/loader.gif and rename it as ajax-loader.gif and put it in root/public/images it should work

Comment: can you update the app on heroku, I really want to see how it's working. and if it's working mark it as accepted (the answer below) so  this question will not be listed in "unanswered questions"

Comment: @Rocket still i couldnt understand, why did you tell "Posting code/a link and saying "fix this" isn't how things work around here. You need to give us detail about your problem, and show that you tried to fix it yourself before asking for help.", how could you think i didn't tried to fix this before posting here?.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 yes, i have updated in heroku, you can check. now problem is solved. thanks again :)

Comment: yes, the error is gone, the image is loading, but it looks ugly somehow, you'll need to find a better one to get the right size. at least in chrome it's not looking very nice. Good luck.

Comment: ok, now this loading image is inside of <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span> element, and JS gives to this element a size of 44px/44px and therefor you'll have to place an gif file with this size. Thanks to google I got one for you just perect: http://www.baharranjbar.com/app_upload/images/loader.gif

Comment: @rmagnum2002 sir, i have one more problem, like after loggin to the app, if we refresh the page, all jquery-mobile's styling will looks ugly. please check n let me know the problem if possible. thanks.

Comment: i need the username and password

Comment: @rmagnum2002 username is : shreedhar@gmail.com
password is : foobar

Comment: @rmagnum2002 i dont think this problem occurs in app which is deployed in heroku, but i am facing this problem when running app in localhost.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 this is screen shot after refreshing the page https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0nS8ywDh-QqcV9VR3ZkR0Flcm8
this is before https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0nS8ywDh-QqU29PSDIxSzJweTg

Comment: well then, I can not see what is the problem there, except one thing I see on Heroku, you have different html id's and classes to the elements, that's why the index page looks nice, like a mobile app, and other pages looks bad.

Comment: one more thing, I never compile the assets while I am in development mode, so I suggest you to remove the assets folder from public/ so the app will load the css only from app/assets. be aware to not delete the images folder where you have the ajax-loader.gif file

Comment: and one more thing, when I am in production mode, only in production I run the rake assets precompile, but before running I remove all old assets that were created at last precompile, if you'll let them, you might get conflicts, so the you must not have any folders or files in public/assets before compiling assets except the IMAGES/ with the loader.gif

Comment: @rmagnum2002 thanks a lot sir, i removed compiled data(except images/ajax-loader.gif) and removed all cookies from browser it works. thank you so much sir :)

Comment: you are welcome, you shouldn't remove the cookies, cookies has nothing  to do with assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, there is one solution I can think of.

Looking at your gem file I see that you use the

```
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
```

I've searched in the github for this gem and I found 2 of them, one edited 1 year ago, and the 2-nd is edited 16 days ago.

I can think only that you use the first one, that is old, but the second one says clear that is for Rails 3.1

but at the same time, both gems requires to use `gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'` in the Gemfile to install it, might be you have the old gem, only this way I can explain why you have the wrong path for your image.

```
`/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif`
```

this is the path for the image if I look in google-inspect you have this line in application.css but in the github repo you have no such line, so I think this is a line that the gem inserts in the application.css

So I would better download the new gem and paste it in the vendor/bundle folder just as you would run the `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle` command.

I will look further for the solution, but for now you should take a look at this `jquery_mobile_rails` gem.

p.s.

if you have now the path `/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif`  that is wrong for rails 3.1 you might try to create this path on your own, just go to root/public/ and create this folder images and place that ajax-loader.gif inside this way the app should find the path.. or not, but it's worth to try it.